# OpenGL - use different polygons one drawcall - instancing

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I am using OpenGL ES version 3 for my android game and have implemented instancing. It works well IF I use a polygon of the same size/dimension that is identical vertices. I can jump to different UV-coordinates of the texture atlas if I want to create change the sprites state for every frame.

```
v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate + uvCoordsOffset[gl_InstanceID];
```

that is .. I just change the texture coordinates with a uniform-vec which consists of offset coordinates.

BUT - here comes the issue.

What if I want to do the same but with sprites that have different dimensions?

in the drawcall ...

```
GLES30.glDrawElementsInstanced(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, 6,  GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexOffset, nFallingObj);
```

I can only send one polygon, that is the green dinosaur vertices in the screenshot. I have this as base polygon and I want to get to the RED dinosaur of the atlas. I can do this easily with texture offset as described above BUT you see how it becomes? the polygon of the green dinosaur is used but I want to be changed as of the red dinosaurs.

Is there any easy solution to this issue? 
thanks in advance!!!

some source-code

the draw-method

```
      public void drawFallingObjects() {

        GLES30.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);

        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, CreateGLContext.POSITION_DATA_SIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, CreateGLContext.STRIDE, 0);

        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle,  CreateGLContext.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_DATA_SIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            CreateGLContext.STRIDE, CreateGLContext.POSITION_DATA_SIZE * CreateGLContext.BYTES_PER_FLOAT);


        GLES30.glUniform2fv(uvCoordsOffsetLoc, nFallingObj, uvOffsetVec, 0);
        GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, nFallingObj, false, mMVPMatrixMajor, 0);

        GLES30.glDrawElementsInstanced(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexOffset, nFallingObj);

    }
```

vertex-shader code

```
  void main()                                                   
{

   v_Color = a_Color;

   v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate + uvCoordsOffset[gl_InstanceID];

   gl_Position =  u_MVPMatrix[gl_InstanceID] * a_Position;

}
```

[image]

Comment: You'll have to bind the correct vertices before drawing.

Comment: The cost of correcting the MVP matrix for each instance every frame is probably more expensive than just animating the batch in software uploading a new vertex buffer.

Comment: @java beside the texture coordinate offset per instance  (`uvCoordsOffset[gl_InstanceID]`) you need a texture scale per instance too. You have to do something like this: `v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate * uvCoordsScale[gl_InstanceID] + uvCoordsOffset[gl_InstanceID];` or combined in a `vec4`: `v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate * uvCoords[gl_InstanceID].zw + uvCoords[gl_InstanceID].xy;`

Comment: @Rabbid76 ok thanks - will look into this

Answer (score 0):

> What if I want to do the same but with sprites that have different
>   dimensions?

Your MVP matrix can encode scale and skew, which is all you need to adjust the on-screen sprite size.

Comment: but if I use glScale the whole sprite is distorted - I just want to adjust the polygon so it can fit the image

Comment: I didn't say use glScale, I said encode a scale and a skew in the MVP matrix. You can distort a rectangle arbitrarily using a matrix transform.